# Passing a Parameter to the function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass the parameter name to the function, but I am unable to pass

```
function interfaceName(x,y,z){      
return "<div class='iconRow2 linkrow'><a href='javascript:mcrloadgraphdata('+x+'')'>"+x+"</a></div>";   
}

function mcrloadgraphdata(interfaceName)
{       
    alert(interfaceName);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt follow your question too well. 
But I guessed what you might be asking.

There appears to be a mistake with Single quote and double quotes in your statement
Try this

```
    function interfaceName(x,y,z){
         return "<div class='iconRow2 linkrow'><a href=\"javascript:mcrloadgraphdata('"+x+"')\">"+x+"</a></div>";
    }

    function mcrloadgraphdata(interfaceName) {
        alert(interfaceName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your return statement by this :

```
return "<div class='iconRow2 linkrow'><a href='javascript:mcrloadgraphdata('"+x+"')'>" + x + "</a></div>";
```